# how to exit if user enter q

Tags: c++, if-statement, execute

When user presses Q it doesnt quit from the program.. What is wrong?? Help please

```
while (true)
{
//promt to user enter or quit
cout<<" Enter five digit number please or Q to quit \n";
cin>> buf; n = atoi (buf.c_str());
cin.ignore(1000,10);

if( n == 'q' || n == 'Q')
    break;

a = n % 10;
b = n / 10000;

if ( ! a == b )
    {
    cout<< "This is not a palindrome \n";
    continue;
    }
// checking the palindrome
n = n % 10;
n = n / 100;

if ( a == b )
    cout<<" This is palindrome\n";
else
    cout<<" This is not a palindrome\n";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you enter a 'q' character, the atoi function can not interpret this input as a number so a zero is returned.
Please refer to this link

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

The most important is the following paragraph:

**If the first sequence of non-whitespace characters in str is not a valid integral number, or if no such sequence exists because either str is empty or it contains only whitespace characters, no conversion is performed and zero is returned.**

In this case str == buf

Answer (score 0):

If you enter `q` or `Q` to this program, it won't convert anything in `atoi`, and `n` will be `0`, not `'q'` or `'Q'`.  The program *will* exit if you enter the numeric value for `'q'` or `'Q'` in your character set, though (`113` or `81`, respectively).

Example:

```
 Enter five digit number please or Q to quit 
12345
 This is not a palindrome
 Enter five digit number please or Q to quit 
12321
 This is palindrome
 Enter five digit number please or Q to quit 
q
 This is palindrome
 Enter five digit number please or Q to quit 
113
```

I'll leave the further debugging/fixing to you.  Note - your program doesn't correctly check for palindromes.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in previous answers, q will be converted to 0 with atoi(). So, basically, in order for the program to quit with a q or Q, use the atoi() conversion after

```
if( n == 'q' || n == 'Q')
     break;
```

This way, n will still be q or Q when you check if the program should quit, and if not, you then convert n to an integer with atoi() and check if it is a palindrome.

Hope I could help

Comment: if( n == '1' || n == '1')
       cin>>buf; n = atoi (buf.c_str());
        break;

Comment: uhm, no... if( n == '1' || n == '1') is the same as if( n == '1'), since you're using OR on two conditions that are the same. My solution works in pretty much the same way as Ed Heal's solution, so if that worked, great, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
if( n == 'q' || n == 'Q')
```

to

```
if( buf[0] == 'q' || buf[0] == 'Q')
```

This will access the first character in the input and compare it with the desired character 'Q' or 'q'

Comment: Can i ask you another question please? There is a hollow square im trying to create which i did but something doesnt work..

Comment: @OruzAysn - I kinda answered that in a comment

Comment: @OruzAysn - You can also up-vote people and/or accept their answer. Doing this will ensure that you are more likely to get a response in the future.